# UIImagePickerController slow to show image

Tags: ios

I have an application that is based on UIImagePickerController, everything is working just fine except, 
When i try to open Panorama images (<220 degree POV) the imagepicker controller is taking a lot of time to open, and display the image.
I know how panorama image can be quite huge as for their resolution, and that i can scale them once they load up depending on their ratio.

But the problem is that due to its initial size when loading the image from the Gallery, its taking a lot of time, 
How can i optimize this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store all the images and reduce the size, then populate it back

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(your_image, your_reduced_scale (0.0 -> 1.0) );
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: Images? I am talking about a single panorama image.
Suppose my gallery contains a lot of image and 1 of them is a panorama one.
When i tap it, then the problem seems to arise.